# switching bootstrap class of hyperlinks with angular

Tags: html, angular, class, hyperlink, bootstrap-4

I have several hyperlinks on the page

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" routerLink='/route1' >First Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" routerLink='/route2' >Second Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" routerLink='/route3' >Third Link</a>
```

First link is highlighted because has class "active". while pressing each link I have some actions, but the first link stays active anyway.
Now how can I move active class to the corresponding link that has being pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use routeLinkActive directive like this

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='/route1' (click)="setActiveItem('first')">First Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='/route2' (click)="setActiveItem('second')">Second Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='/route3' (click)="setActiveItem('third')">Third Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ngClass for conditionally switching active element:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Add `(click)` action to every `a` element, and inside called function set active element:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="{'active': activeItem === 'first'}" routerLink='/route1' (click)="setActiveItem('first')">First Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="{'active': activeItem === 'second'}"routerLink='/route2' (click)="setActiveItem('second')">Second Link</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="{'active': activeItem === 'third'}" routerLink='/route3' (click)="setActiveItem('third')">Third Link</a>
```

in ts file:

```
activeItem: string;

setActiveItem(activeItem: string): void {
  this.activeItem = activeItem;
}
```

Comment: can you write simple example ? I understand that ngClass can add class, but how can I do it pressing link, and how to add class to exaxctly the same link that was pressed ?

Comment: thanks for the help but routerLinkActive solved my problem perfectly